# Where do I find the workflow id of an automation in Mailchimp?

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I would like to use Mailchimp Api 3.0 to add a subscriber to an automation workflow, but I can't find where the `workflow_id` or `workflow_email_id` are located... this is from the documentation:

> POST /automations/{workflow_id}/emails/{workflow_email_id}/queue   Add a subscriber to a workflow email

http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/automations/emails/queue/

Can anyone tell me to find it? It's probably somewhere really obvious. I mean the `list_id` is well covered, but I can't find any info about this.

Comment: It seems like I have found the answer, so for anyone who may have had the same question, here is what you need to do to get the workflow id:

Using the API endpoint: Get automations

http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/automations/

You'll see that the Response body parameters return everything about the automations, including the id.

Comment: Instead of posting a comment containing the answer, please post your own answer below and accept it 48 hours later, so it can help anyone who read this question.

Comment: Thanks @ekad I've answered the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is found in the official mailchimp knowledge base: It explains that you simply **go into the workflow and read the id from the URL.**

Other ways to get id information about anything:

1. Using the API endpoint, detailed here: http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/automations/
   You'll see that the Response body parameters return everything about the automations, including the id.
2. Probably the easier way: use the developer playground https://us1.api.mailchimp.com/playground/?_ga=1.218336095.774374564.1480036371

So, once you set up your lists and automations, go into the playground, and you'll find all the ids you'll need for everything.

Comment: Using the playground worked to get the automation id but reading the url from the workflow did not work for me. The url looked like "...mailchimp.com/campaigns/wizard/autocampaigns?id=1922417" and "1922417" was not the workflow id

Answer (score 5):

I found this confusing as well. Here is how I got the answer:

1. Send a GET request to `https://us9.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/automations` to find the workflow_id
2. With the workflow_id, send a GET request to `https://us9.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/automations/<workflow_id>/emails` to find the workflow_email_id. The workflow_email_id will be the "id" in the array that's returned.
3. From there you can make POST requests to `https://us9.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/automations/<workflow_id>/emails/<workflow_email_id>/queue`

Keep in mind you might need to subscribe an email address to a list first for the post request to work. To subscribe you can use: `https://us9.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/<list_id>` with your data:

```
{
  "members": [{
        "email_address" : "emailaddress@whatever.com",
        "status": "subscribed"
  }]
}
```

Comment: This is the answer that works for me. Also, using MailChim.Net.V3, you can call `mailChimpManager.Automations.GetAllAsync()`. Then from the results use the `Id` and call  `mailChimpManager.AutomationEmails.GetAllAsync(workflowId)` as suggested above.